# How to make UICollectionViewCells have rounded corners and drop shadows?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've seen some other answers to similar questions, but none of the solutions have worked for me, even with some tweaking.

As the title suggests, I would like my `UICollectionViewCell`s to have rounded corners and drop shadows (or shadows on all sides except the top). What I have done so far is to add two views to my `UICollectionViewCell` - `mainView`, which displays the cell's necessary content and has rounded corners, and `shadowView`, which has the shadow. Neither view is a subview of the other, they exist together in the same cell. They are both the exact same dimensions, and `mainView` is obviously displayed on top of `shadowView`. Here is my current code implementation:

```
let mainView = cell.viewWithTag(1003) as! UIView       
mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
mainView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
mainView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
mainView.layer.masksToBounds = true

let shadowView = cell.viewWithTag(1002) as! UIView
shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false
shadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shadowView.bounds, cornerRadius: mainView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
```

Here is what this code produces:
[image]
One would think that `mainView`'s corners aren't rounded enough, and that the shadow isn't big enough.

However, upon removing `shadowView` and setting the `UICollectionView`'s background to black, you can see that `mainView`'s corners are actually quite rounded:
[image]

So this implies that the issue is with `shadowView`'s shadow size. However, I have tried increasing the shadow offsets and the the shadow radius, which did nothing. Most changes either produced a very thick shadow around `mainView`, decreased `mainView`'s rounding even more, or did nothing.

Here is an image of the relevant `UITableViewCell`'s view hierarchy in the Storyboard:
[image]

Comment: How did you manage to add spacing left and right to your cell? My cell's shadow gets cut off by the containerview

Answer (score 7):

Here is the `Cell` code:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)


        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here is the usage code:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView!.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

Thanks for the chat on Hangouts. I downloaded your code and `mainView` and `shadowView` was nil.

- I noticed that you're not comfortable with CollectionViewCells.

With that being said. I'm more than happy to introduce our friend `Runtime Attributes`

Without touching your code. Select a view and add your `runtime attribute key` and set the value.

[image: Scr1]

Output:

[image: Scre1]

Go ahead, and do the work for the shadow and the rest.

---

The `mainView` is rounded, but the `shadowView` is taking all the credit.

You need to enable `clipsToBounds` on both views:

```
mainView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: After enabling `clipsToBounds` on both views, no shadows nor rounded corners at all are being displayed.

Comment: Isn’t ‘mainView’ a subview of shadow view?! Correct me if I am wrong; I’ll update my code

Comment: No, they are separate views in the same cell.

Comment: @Kevin2566 what does “separate” mean? One of them has to be the root view.

Comment: The root view is the Collection View. The cell I am referring to only contains two views - `shadowView` and `mainView`. There isn't a singular root view inside of the cell itself.